# Regex - how to exclude 4 digit number from wider numeric pattern

Tags: python, regex

Really tried to browse and search if this specific question has been posted previously, so I hope I'm not asking an obvious one here.

My problem: I have a regex expression, with few different possible criteria for pattern matching separated by pipes. I'm OK with all of them except one, where I basically want to:

- Find any expression which would be number between 4 and 6 digits (regardless of position in the string)
- Exclude from this pattern expressions which would relate to years in this century (so starting with 20 and followed by two digits)

So for example, I would like to match: 4149, 20259, 202046, but would like to exclude 2019 as it will refer to a year and not the code I'm searching for.

Currently, I tried applying this one (only last part of the expression): **|\d{4,6}?!20\d{2})** , but it's not working properly. I know that the expressions preceeding pipe are fine and was able to notice that \d{4,6} stops to work once I add the "exclusion" in this case, so I assume I'm not using the ?! properly. Could I ask you for an advice on this one?

Edit: Solved! Thank you very much for immediate answers (I was really positively surprised how fast there were few alternative solutions). Sorry I had to pick just one, all of others would be adjustable and viable for my needs, I just found this one most appealing and tailored for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where I'm not sure if word-boundaries are your best bet to indicate boundaries (maybe `\D` is better?), you could try:

```
\b(?!20\d\d\b)\d{4,6}\b
```

See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wsmc5A/9)

---

- `\b` - Word boundary.
- `(?!20\d\d\b)` - Negative lookahead: No literal 20 followed by two digits and a word boundary.
- `\d{4,6}` - Four to six digits.
- `\b` - Word boundary.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thank you JvdV! I think this solution should match 100% of the cases I might come across. As this is externally provided database I'm working on I cannot be 100% sure, but I assume that the exception (4 digit year number) should be always surrounded by whitespaces (or be at the beginning/end of the string) and then potentially surrounded by alphanumeric codes/strings. As far as I understand this will still meet the criteria, otherwise I will probably manage to adjust it somehow.

Comment: Perfect, glad it helped you out @Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regular expression.

```
r'\b(?:20\d{3,4}|2[1-9]\d{2,4}|[1,3-9]\d{3,5})\b'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NPPQ6F/2/)

Comment: Note that this excludes the year 2000, even though it occurred in the 20th century. :-)

Comment: Just seen this pop-up. Can I make a remark here Cary as this seems to ignore numbers like `2222` and the likes. Is this intentional?

Comment: @JvdV, thanks for the catch. I think it's fixed now, but please cast your eagle-eye once more.

Comment: Seems to do the trick. (though prejudiced, my own answer just seems visually more appealing haha)

Comment: @Jvdv, yours also wins in Code Golf.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
[013-9][1-9]\d{2}|\d{5,6}
```

Match all 4 digit sequences, except the ones starting with 20, and all 5 or 6 digit sequences